# Cloud function deployment time

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am deploying a function to cloud function, but it takes substantial time to deploy. How can I optimize my deployment?

I have tried deployed with and without go.mod. I have also tried include vendor (go mod vendor).

gcloud functions deploy FuncX --entry-point FuncX --runtime go111 --trigger-http

Answer (score 4):

I've observed similar behavior. This seems to happen when your `go.mod` file includes large packages that need to be fetched during deployment. To streamline deployments make sure, you can vendor your dependencies (`go mod tidy`, `go mod vendor`).

Note that if you your deployed files include a `go.mod` file, [the vendor directory will be ignored](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime#vendor_directory). If you deploy your functions using the gcloud CLI, create a `.gcloudignore` file in your project's directory and add `go.mod` and `go.sum` to that file.

For example:

.gcloudignore

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
go.mod
go.sum
```

In my case it reduced deployment time up to 4 times.